# Best way to return data from one python file to another

Tags: python

I have a python script which defines step to take in an experiment `definition.py`, and another python script which executes the experiment `execute.py`. The first file I want to think of as data moreso than code; when an experiment is executed a folder is created for it, `definition.py` is moved into the folder, and any data generated from the experiment is saved there as well.

I intend to call `execute.py` like

```
execute.py -f save_stuff_here -d this_is_the_definition.py
```

but I'm not sure what the best way to accomplish this is. Other questions on stackoverflow have suggested importing the definition, but I don't think that will work for me. I have no assurance that the definition is somewhere in the `PYTHONPATH`, nor that the definition has the same name. I'd prefer it need not be, as the user should be providing that information.

The `definition.py` needs to define a single object (a list of actions), and `execute.py` needs to be able to refer to the object.

The ideal behaviour I would like is that `script1.py path/to/script2.py` return a value from `script2.py` to `script1.py`, where `path/to/script2.py` is any arbitrary file.

Can it be done?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Just a friendly note regarding your question, you can format inline code snippets using backticks and format code blocks by indenting four spaces. It helps everyone understand the question a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

[`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) the file with an explicit `globals` dict. You can get at anything defined in the file by reading the `globals` dict. If you need Python 3 compatibility, you can `open` the file, `read` the contents, and `exec` them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need send data from path/to/script2.py to script1.py once the script2.py finish to run?
Did you try..?

script2.py

```
import os
data = "whatever"
os.system("python ..//..//script1.py %s" % data)
```

script1.py

```
import sys
data = sys.argv[1]
print "my data is: " + data
raw_input('enter to finish')
```

Answer (score 0):

using `os` and `sys` you can get the command line arguments of a python program and use them to execute another python program

```
import sys
import os
filename = sys.argv[1]
os.system(filename)
```

This will take the first CLI as a filename input and call it, for example:

```
script1.py script2.py
```

will make script1 call script2